# Does LXQt taskbar support svg icons?

Tags: icons, lxqt

It was reported in a GitHub [issue](https://github.com/johnfactotum/foliate/issues/456) that the icons of a GTK application Foliate does not appear in the LXQt taskbar.

[image]

Foliate ships with an svg icon file, and it has been verified that the icon appears in Gnome's dash, KDE's taskbar, as well as Cinnamon's taskbar.
So, does LXQt's taskbar not support svg files? What else can lead to this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, LxQt does support SVG icons. In GTK apps one can enable the icon by adding the line following line to the appropriate source file.

```
Gtk.Window.set_default_icon_name(pkg.name)
```

[Source](https://github.com/johnfactotum/foliate/commit/0fdf844925b2c23b70edb6bccb6fdfcb010646cb)